# In MySQL Workbench 6.1 (OS X), can you make the Result Grid taller?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In MySQL Workbench 6.1 (OS X), can you make the Result Grid taller?

I know the region expands to fill the space vacated by Action Output/Text Output/History, should you choose to hide that.

But I'd like to shrink the space used by the Queries (i.e. "Query 1") and make the Result Grid taller (at the expense of the Queries tabs). Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this:
[image]

Place your mouse on the line between the grid toolbar and the editor bottom. It's only a few pixel so watch out. The cursor image should change to a split cursor and you can drag that line to resize both, editor and grid. On Mac the split cursor sometimes does not appear, but otherwise it still works moving the split position.